# Python If-elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Quick question, I'm working on a program that takes a number from a user and uses an algorithm to try to beat their score. Anyways, when they pick a number from the list it should store it into the humanint variable, however when I do elif the terminal just closes past the input of the number. any ideas?

```
numbers = 16, 9, 12, -14, -9, -10
print (numbers)
humanint = input("What number will you place your piece on?")
print ("Player 1 (Black) selects " + humanint + "!")
print("(*) Denotes terminal value (sum)")

if (humanint == 16):
    mmtree = '[{A:16} [{B:9} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:28}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:7}]] [{F:9} [{*K:6}]] ]'
elif (humanint == 9):
    mmtree = '[{A:9} [{B:16} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-5}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:0}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-1}]] ]'
elif (humanint == 12):
    mmtree = '[{A:12} [{B:16} [{*G:28}]] [{C:9} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:3}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:2}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -14):
    mmtree = '[{A:-14} [{B:16} [{*G:2}]] [{C:9} [{*H:-5}]] [{D:12} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-24}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -9):
    mmtree = '[{A:-9} [{B:16} [{*G:7}]] [{C:9} [{*H:0}]] [{D:12} [{*I:3}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-19}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -10):
    mmtree = '[{A:-10} [{B:16} [{*G:6}]] [{C:9} [{*H:1}]] [{D:12} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-24}]] [{F:-9} [{*K:-19}]] ]'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem more? Do you mean when you input value for `humanint` such that `elif` portion is hit you do not get any output? Do you get output for `if` block? You do not seem to be printint anything in th `if..elif` block, what output are you expecting?

Comment: please describe us the error you are getting

Comment: Open the terminal first, and then run your script. If you simply run your script, it will open the terminal, run, and then close as soon as it's complete.

Comment: When humanint is first initialized, it allows me to enter a number. After initialization, if i attempt to return or get a value from the elif block (mmtree) the program crashes. Typecasting the raw input did not work.

Comment: Like I asked, please explain what you mean by crashed. Did you get any error? Or just no output? What else were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting the string to be printed depending on what number the user inputs. For example, if the number the user inputs is 16, the string outputted should be:    [{A:16} [{B:9} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:28}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:7}]] [{F:9} [{*K:6}]] ] The terminal closes once I input a number for humanint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to digress, but I think using so many elif's is not pythonic. You should use a dict instead.

```
options = {
16: '[{A:16} [{B:9} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:28}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:7}]] [{F:9} [{*K:6}]] ]',
9: '[{A:9} [{B:16} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-5}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:0}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-1}]] ]',
12: '[{A:12} [{B:16} [{*G:28}]] [{C:9} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:3}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:2}]] ]',
-14: '[{A:-14} [{B:16} [{*G:2}]] [{C:9} [{*H:-5}]] [{D:12} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-24}]] ]',
9: '[{A:-9} [{B:16} [{*G:7}]] [{C:9} [{*H:0}]] [{D:12} [{*I:3}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-19}]] ]',
-10: '[{A:-10} [{B:16} [{*G:6}]] [{C:9} [{*H:1}]] [{D:12} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-24}]] [{F:-9} [{*K:-19}]] ]'
}


humanint = int(input("What number will you place your piece on?"))
mmtree = options.get(humanint)
```

Comment: should use `[]` instead of `get` for immediate `KeyError` on an unrecognized option (Python Zen, koan 10).

Comment: get on dict returns None, not key error, which can very well be handled

Answer (score 2):

the function raw_input will always return a string and not an integer. You will need to typecast the user input like this,

```
humanint = int(input("What number will you place your piece on?"))
```

Update : To find the problem I tried running the code in my machine. Turns out there was also an issue where you were concatenating the string inside print. The following seems to work for me in Python 2.7

```
numbers = 16, 9, 12, -14, -9, -10
print (numbers)
humanint = input("What number will you place your piece on?")
print ("Player 1 (Black) selects " + str(humanint) + "!")
print("(*) Denotes terminal value (sum)")

if (humanint == 16):
    mmtree = '[{A:16} [{B:9} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:28}]] [{D:-14}[{*I:2}]][{E:-9} [{*J:7}]] [{F:9} [{*K:6}]] ]'
elif (humanint == 9):
    mmtree = '[{A:9} [{B:16} [{*G:25}]] [{C:12} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-5}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:0}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-1}]] ]'
elif (humanint == 12):
    mmtree = '[{A:12} [{B:16} [{*G:28}]] [{C:9} [{*H:21}]] [{D:-14} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:3}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:2}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -14):
    mmtree = '[{A:-14} [{B:16} [{*G:2}]] [{C:9} [{*H:-5}]] [{D:12} [{*I:-2}]] [{E:-9} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-24}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -9):
    mmtree = '[{A:-9} [{B:16} [{*G:7}]] [{C:9} [{*H:0}]] [{D:12} [{*I:3}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-23}]] [{F:-10} [{*K:-19}]] ]'
elif (humanint == -10):
    mmtree = '[{A:-10} [{B:16} [{*G:6}]] [{C:9} [{*H:1}]] [{D:12} [{*I:2}]] [{E:-14} [{*J:-24}]] [{F:-9} [{*K:-19}]] ]'

print mmtree
```

Comment: I tried typecasting like you suggested but still crashes once the program hits elif block.

Comment: In your comments I see that you said  "I'm expecting the string to be printed depending on what number the user inputs". However I don't see any print statement.

You should add `print mmtree` at the end of the file.

Comment: That's what's causing the terminal to close, attempting to access the elif block in any way. I've tried printing out mmtree.